# Can I call a function by name in f#?

Tags: f#

Is there any way to call a function by name in F#? Given a string, I want to pluck a function value from the global namespace (or, in general, a given module), and call it. I know the type of the function already.

Why would I want to do this? I'm trying to work around fsi not having an --eval option. I have a script file that defines many int->() functions, and I want to execute one of them. Like so:

```
fsianycpu --use:script_with_many_funcs.fsx --eval "analyzeDataSet 1"
```

My thought was to write a trampoline script, like:

```
fsianycpu --use:script_with_many_funcs.fsx trampoline.fsx analyzeDataSet 1
```

In order to write "trampoline.fsx", I'd need to look up the function by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this, but you can implement it using .NET reflection. The idea is to search through all types available in the current assembly (this is where the current code is compiled) and dynamically invoke the method with the matching name. If you had this in a module, you'd have to check the type name too.

```
// Some sample functions that we might want to call
let hello() = 
  printfn "Hello world"

let bye() = 
  printfn "Bye"

// Loader script that calls function by name
open System
open System.Reflection

let callFunction name = 
  let asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  for t in asm.GetTypes() do
    for m in t.GetMethods() do
      if m.IsStatic && m.Name = name then 
        m.Invoke(null, [||]) |> ignore

// Use the first command line argument (after -- in the fsi call below)
callFunction fsi.CommandLineArgs.[1]
```

This runs hello world when called by:

```
fsi --use:C:\temp\test.fsx --exec -- "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. @jbtule's answer looks more complex, but also possibly more robust. When the simple answer works, I like the simple answer. :-)

Comment: The good simple answer will fall down in the interactive scenario, when each partial compilation adds a type and a static method of the same name to the executing assembly. And how to discern between let-bound functions and static members on types?

Answer (score 4):

You can use reflection to get the functions as `MethodInfo`'s by FSharp function name

```
open System
open System.Reflection

let rec fsharpName (mi:MemberInfo) =
    if mi.DeclaringType.IsNestedPublic then
        sprintf "%s.%s" (fsharpName mi.DeclaringType) mi.Name
    else
        mi.Name

let functionsByName = 
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                |> Seq.filter (fun t -> t.IsPublic || t.IsNestedPublic) 
                |> Seq.collect (fun t -> t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public))
                |> Seq.filter (fun m -> not m.IsSpecialName)
                |> Seq.groupBy (fun m -> fsharpName m)
                |> Map.ofSeq
                |> Map.map (fun k v -> Seq.exactlyOne v)
```

You can then invoke the MethodInfo

```
functionsByName.[fsharpFunctionNameString].Invoke(null, objectArrayOfArguments)
```

But you probably need to do more work to parse your string arguments using the `MethodInfo.GetParameters()` types as a hint.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [FSharp.Compiler.Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html) to make your own `fsi.exe` with an eval flag

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

[<EntryPoint>]
let main(argv) =

    let argAll = Array.append [| "C:\\fsi.exe" |] argv
    let argFix = argAll |> Array.map (fun a -> if a.StartsWith("--eval:") then "--noninteractive" else a)
    let optFind = argv |> Seq.tryFind (fun a -> a.StartsWith "--eval:")
    let evalData = if optFind.IsSome then
                        optFind.Value.Replace("--eval:",String.Empty)
                     else
                        String.Empty
    let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration()
    let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession(fsiConfig, argFix, Console.In, Console.Out, Console.Error) 
    if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(evalData) then
        fsiSession.Run()
    else
        fsiSession.EvalInteraction(evalData)
    0
```

If the above was compiled into `fsieval.exe` it could be used as so

```
fsieval.exe --load:script_with_many_funcs.fsx --eval:analyzeDataSet` 1
```