# Dynamic Function Call in FSharp

Tags: function, dynamic, f#

Is it possible to take an FSharp function and convert it to a Dynamic function, alternatively is something like this coming to FSharp in the future?

```
let func (a:int) (b:int) : int =
    a + b

let dynamicFunc = FSharpFunc.ToDynamicFunc(func)

let argumentList = [1; 2]

let object = dynamicFunc argumentList 

let result = object :?> int
```

It appears that you currently have to fall back to standard reflection (like this: [calling a F# function by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909506/can-i-call-a-function-by-name-in-f)) however, this approach seems very brittle. Mainly because there's no real guarantee it works, and you have to know what's going on under the covers.

Something like this could be used to wrap any function and do things dynamically.

```
let wrapFun (x:'f) : 'f =

    let args = FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetFunctionElements <| x.GetType()

    let runner (any:obj list) : obj =
        // Do extra things
        FSharpFunc.DynamicInvoke x

    FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeFunction (typeof<'f>, runner) :?> 'f
```

Comment: Could you give a more realistic use case?  There are various ways to do things dynamically, but I'd generally avoid them if at all possible because they just make it easier to introduce errors.  In your particular example, you have a function `func` with a statically known type, so calling it dynamically doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: In this case, I was thinking about a remote call where so calling a wrapped function would collect the arguments and send them to a remote machine where it would actually call the function.

Answer (score 0):

F# does support the dynamic call operator. But you must implement yours. Here is a sample Implementation taken from http://www.fssnip.net/2U/title/Dynamic-operator-using-Dynamic-Language-Runtime

```
// Reference C# implementation of dynamic operations
#r "Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder

// Simple implementation of ? operator that works for instance
// method calls that take a single argument and return some result
let (?) (inst:obj) name (arg:'T) : 'R =
  // TODO: For efficient implementation, consider caching of call sites 
  // Create dynamic call site for converting result to type 'R
  let convertSite = 
    CallSite<Func<CallSite, Object, 'R>>.Create
      (Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof<'R>, null))

  // Create call site for performing call to method with the given
  // name and a single parameter of type 'T
  let callSite = 
    CallSite<Func<CallSite, Object, 'T, Object>>.Create
      (Binder.InvokeMember
        ( CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, null, null, 
          [| CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null);
             CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) |]))

  // Run the method call using second call site and then 
  // convert the result to the specified type using first call site
  convertSite.Target.Invoke
    (convertSite, callSite.Target.Invoke(callSite, inst, arg))
```

You'd be able to use it as follows

```
// Dynamically invoke 'Next' method of 'Random' type
let o = box (new Random())
let a : int = o?Next(10)
```

As for the params you'd have to pass them as a `Tuple` something like

`target?method(param1, param2)` that would mean that the target method processes its argument as a Tuple and as such, some pattern matching may or may not be involved